# How do I upload an image through a PHP file on Windows Phone with C#?

Tags: c#, php, image, upload, windows-8.1

I am unable to upload a file through PHP on Windows Phone 8.1 with C#.

It works perfectly on my localhost machine but does not work on my webserver!

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
if(!is_dir($uploaddir))
{
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
}
else
{
echo 'Dir doesnt exist!';
}
?>
```

And here is my C#:

```
    public async Task UploadImageTask(StorageFile file)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/");
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("fileToUpload");
        form.Add(content, "fileToUpload");
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        content = new StreamContent(stream);
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "fileToUpload",
            FileName = file.Name
        };
        form.Add(content);
        await client.PostAsync("uploadanimage.php", form);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        DebugInfo = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //DebugInfo is a string which returns the source of my website's homepage. all 404's redirect to the homepage aswell. if I send something thats not a storage file, i get a "Possible File Upload Attack"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have figured it out! My server had ModSec and Mod_Security turned out! I contacted my hosting, removed it, and presto!! It works!